Where is redis.conf when installed using snap
SNAP is very confusing. I've installed redis & it's up. I need to configure that thing. The problem is it seems the redis.conf is nowhere, previously it was in /etc/redis/redis.conf.
How to configure SNAP version of Redis?
FYI:
Ubuntu: 24.04
Redis: 7.2.4

does this how-to answer your question?

Unfortunately no. Config file /etc/redis/redis.conf is not exist when installing from snap

What did you research? Try https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/unable-to-locate-redis-conf-file-after-installing-it-using-snap/24453

I've check that post before posting question here. unfortunately there's no files like that

It's incredible that no one has the answer. The snap package works, but I cannot find where the config file is. I don't even understand how the dang thing runs without an obvious config file.

See my answer below. I think I figured it out.

Digging around, here is what I found:
There is no redis.conf file at all if installed via snap.
However, you can configure the server in the command line client: redis.cli.
Use the CONFIG get * command to see all configuration entries.
See: https://redis.io/docs/latest/commands/config-get/

This makes snap version almost useless.

You might be able to configure it using a lua script.

That'll be a hack, not a solution.
